# Bevel and Resolution Multiple Selected Curves

Tags: bezier-curves, bevel, svg, resolution

I imported an SVG Character and grouped/parented it in an empty object for easier positioning.

I selected all (A+shift left click method) the character objects (hair, eyes, pants, etc:) However, when I try to bevel it only bevels what was first selected.

Is there a way in Blender to "Bevel and Resolution Multiple Selected Curves" without having to do it individually?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either press the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key while clicking a property to assign it to all selected objects; or assign the bevel object to one of the curves, then right click over the property and choose *Copy to Selected* option.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Select the curves you want to bevel and set the parameters for the active curve.
press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> and select **Object Data** to transfer the settings to the other curves.

Comment: This will link selected curves object data, making them instances sharing the same geometry and shape.