# Why are my property changes to selected curves only applying to one curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, properties

If I select multiple curves, then change the properties, then the changes will only work on one curve. How do I make it work on all my selected curves?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104461/bevel-and-resolution-multiple-selected-curves

Answer (score 1):

When you have selected multiple objects and would like to change properties for all of them simultaneously, you have to hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then change the value. Otherwise the value gets changed only for the active (selected) object.